# Gtkmm add/Remove widget leaks Why?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

When I add a widget to container, then I remove it. Widget is leaked, why ?
I used a "MyWidget" to spy widget deletion but I get same result from a classic Gtk::Label.
Code below have been tested on two distro.

```
#include <iostream>
// gtkmm30-3.24.5-1.el9.x86_64
// or gtkmm3 3.24.7-1 (arch)
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include <gtkmm/builder.h>
#include <gtkmm/label.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/box.h>

#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class MyWidget : public Gtk::Label{
public:
    MyWidget(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& builder);
    virtual ~MyWidget();
};

MyWidget::~MyWidget(){
    cout << "MyWidget::~MyWidget()" << endl;
}

MyWidget::MyWidget(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& builder)
 : Gtk::Label(cobject)
{
    assert(builder);
}

int main()
{
    Gtk::Main main;
    
    // Create widget
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("widget.glade");
    MyWidget* widget = nullptr;
    builder->get_widget_derived("widget", widget);

    {
        Gtk::Window window;
        window.add(*widget);
        // Use window ....
        window.remove(); // No leak if this line is commented
    }
    
    builder.reset();
    cout << G_OBJECT(widget->gobj())->ref_count << endl; // Print => 1
    // Expected to see "MyWidget::~MyWidget()" but No ! Why ?
}
```

I expected to see ~MyWidget destructor executed.

This is my glade file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.40.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkLabel" id="widget">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="label" translatable="yes">widget</property>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: What is this call : `window.remove()`? I don't see it in the 3.24 docs... I think `widget` should be an argument to this call.

Comment: If you add your Glade file, I will try your code.

Comment: `Gtk::Container::remove(Gtk::Widget&)` is not available on a Gtk::Window only remove()  which remove all added widgets. I added my glade file. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ah yes, from `Gtk::Bin`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incorrect assumption we made here is that `Gtk::Window::remove()` destroys the widget it removes, but in reality, it only removes its reference from the parent container. I instrumented your code with extra `cout`s to see what was happening and when this line is executed:

```cpp
builder->get_widget_derived("widget", widget);
```

A `MyWidget` instance is created by the builder. At this point, the builder owns a reference to it and the ref count is one. Then, when the following line is executed:

```cpp
window.add(*widget);
```

the window, which is a one element container as you pointed out, takes a (owning) reference on the `MyWidget` instance. So the reference count on the `MyWidget` instance is now 2: one for the builder, one for the window. This is where it gets tricky. When executing:

```cpp
window.remove();
```

the window "removes" its reference to the `MyWidget` instance, in the sense that it will no longer `show` it, but the reference count on it is not decremented. At this point, there are still two references on the `MyWidget` instance: one for the builder, and one that is not owned by anyone (it is leaked, unless someone explicitly calls `delete` on it). When this line is executed:

```cpp
builder.reset();
```

The builder is destroyed, and its reference to the `MyWidget` instance is removed, bringing the reference count on it to one. This is why printing the reference count always prints "1" in your case.

Now if we comment out:

```cpp
window.remove();
```

What happens it that at the end of `main`, the window destroys itself and the widget it references (if any). In your case, this is the `MyWidget` instance, so the destructor is called and the reference count is brought to 0. You don't see it printed because it happens after the `cout` call, at the `}` (end of scope for `main`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you consider this behavior as expected ?. What kind of "relationship" do ref counting of widget and smart pointer of Builder (Glib::RefPtr) have ?

Comment: I consider it as "expected". The `Gtk::Bin::remove` documentation does not document it, however here is the documentation for `Gtk::Container::remove` (3.24): *[...] If widget is managed with `Gtk::manage()`, and you don't want to use widget again, then you should delete it, because there will no longer be any parent container to delete it automatically.*

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help. This end my question/topic. My issue is resolved.

Comment: Ok, please do not forget to click the "accept button" to accept the answer otherwise people will think the issue is not resolved. Thanks!